# How to have deeper URL with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I know the rule of *mydomain.com/controller/action* URL, but is it possible to have URL like *mydomain.com/controller/action/more*, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible.
use [routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) concept

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Is this the only way?

Comment: it's only legal way ;). besides, you may pass some GET-params via this mechanism. e.g. your route may look like article/:category/:page so in controller code you will automatically get url params such as category and page number (for pagination issue)

Comment: Ok, I'll see it. Thank you again :)